# Can I safely delete the migrate tables after migration?

Tags: 8, migrations

I passed a site from d7 to d8
I wanted to know if I can delete tables db migrate map d7 and migrate messages d7
they are more than a hundred
I can delete db tables migrate map d7 and migrate d7 messages of types of content that no longer exist on d8?

http://fortecad.altervista.org/ottomigratemapImmagine.jpg

http://fortecad.altervista.org/ottomigratemessaggeImmagine.jpg

regards

Comment: You probably have a copy of your site running locally, no? So, simply make a database backup, delete those tables, see what happens. If FUBAR, drop DB and import the backup. No?

Comment: If you sure about completed migrations. You can uninstall module and deleted all table _map and _message of migrations. It's safe.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If you're doing a "one-and-done" migration you can remove the tables. Just make sure to:

- uninstall the migration modules
- remove your relevant migration config
- then remove your DB tables once you have no code/config dependant on these tables.

Note, the caveat is you're wiping out your migration history.

The migration framework has an [ongoing issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2713327) about this topic. These tables are persisted since these they capture migration source/destination metadata. The metadata is important if you have a phased, or ongoing, migration. If your migration project is over, the metadata has no relevance.

Comment: Yep, once you uninstall there’s no going back unless you have a copy of the db before migration.